# Unable to deploy nodejs service due to build issue on openshift

Tags: openshift, redhat

I am trying to implement a node js mongo db based app on CRC On MAC.
here is the `template.json` in place  `https://github.com/nirmesh/openshift-taxcalc/blob/master/openshift/templates/taxcalc-template.json`

However i am seeing issue error :

> instantiating Build from BuildConfig demo1/taxcalc (0): Error resolving ImageStreamTag nodejs:4 in namespace openshift: unable to find latest tagged image

What should I do ? I tried some new version but does not help. I am new to `openshift` How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to find a valid image stream name and tag for Node.js. You can see the available image streams on your cluster like so:

```
oc get is -n openshift | grep nodejs
```

Then change the ImageStreamTag in your template, i.e change `nodejs:4` to `nodejs:16-ubi8` or similar. Of course, your Node.js application might break if it was designed for Node.js v4.

You could also make an image stream that contains the old Node.js image: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.12/openshift_images/image-streams-manage.html